# Reading & writing a configuration file on an Adafruit Circuit Playground Express

Tags: adafruit, flash, json

I would like to store an application's configuration in a file stored on the Circuit Playground Express (CPX) flash. The application itself needs to be able to update the configuration file. Things I need to store are basic, for example:

- NeoPixel brightness (eg. brightness = 0.9)
- NeoPixels on/off (eg. NP_enable = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]

ArduinoJason seems appropriate, but I cannot even get to the point of writing files to the CPX. The TinyUSB libraries are supposed to give the ability to write to the CPX SPI Flash, but I cannot get any of the examples included with this library to compile.
I am trying to compile the msc_external_flash example provided with the TinyUSB library. I get the following 2 errors:

```
In file included from /home/pi/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_TinyUSB_Library/examples/MassStorage/msc_external_flash/msc_external_flash.ino:28:0:
/home/pi/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_TinyUSB_Library/src/Adafruit_TinyUSB.h:31:2: error: #error TinyUSB is not selected, please select it in "Tools->Menu->USB Stack"
#error TinyUSB is not selected, please select it in "Tools->Menu->USB Stack"
^~~~~
msc_external_flash:65:6: error: #error No QSPI/SPI flash are defined on your board variant.h !
#error No QSPI/SPI flash are defined on your board variant.h !
^~~~~
```

The board selected is SAMD-->Circuit Playground Express.
There is no Tools menu item for selecting the USB stack.

Regarding the second error,
From msc_external_flash.ino:

```
  #if defined(EXTERNAL_FLASH_USE_QSPI)
    Adafruit_FlashTransport_QSPI flashTransport;
  #elif defined(EXTERNAL_FLASH_USE_SPI)
    Adafruit_FlashTransport_SPI flashTransport(EXTERNAL_FLASH_USE_CS, EXTERNAL_FLASH_USE_SPI);
  #else
    #error No QSPI/SPI flash are defined on your board variant.h !
  #endif
```

of the files named variant.h, this looks like the best candidate:
/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/samd/1.8.12/variants/circuitplay/variant.h

but the file does not contain the string "EXTERNAL_FLASH", nor anything I see that is CPX specific.

Arduino version is 1.8.19, which I am running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Buster.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: please describe the problem and ask a question ... this site is not a forum

Comment: [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org/) has an example that reads a configuration file from the SD card. See [JsonConfigFile.ino](https://arduinojson.org/v6/example/config/). You can easily adapt it for any other filesystem, such as SPIFFS and LittleFS.

Comment: install the Adafruit SAMD core. it looks like you are using the Arduino SAMD core, which has only basic support for the Adaruit board

Comment: The board selected is SAMD-->Circuit Playground Express. I can run other CPX examples, like IRNeoPixels, I assume I have the Adafruit SAMD core.

Comment: yes but you can't compile Adafruit specialties with the Arduino SAMD core

Answer (score 3):

The problem was using the Arduino SAMD board core instead of the Adafruit SAMD board core. The Adafruit SAMD board core is not visible unless you add:
https://adafruit.github.io/arduino-board-index/package_adafruit_index.json

to the "Additional Boards Manager URLs:" field of the Arduino IDE preferences panel.

Once you do that...
Then install the "Adafruit SAMD Boards" from the Arduino IDE Boards Manager.
Then select the menu item:
Tools -->
Board: -->
Adafruit SAMD (32-bits ARM Cortext-M0+ and Cortext-M4) boards -->
Adafruit Circuit Playground Express (SAMD21)

I have not seen this procedure in any Adafruit documentation.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/setup